# Node.js express MySQL check for success

Tags: mysql, node.js

Currently my function looks like this

```
module.exports.processForm = function(req, res) {
    req.assert('username', 'Username field is required').notEmpty();
    req.assert('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
    if (req.validationErrors()) {
        res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: req.validationErrors()});
    }
    db.query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1', req.body.username, function(errs, data) {
        if (errs) {
            res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: 'Wrong password / username'});
        }
    });  
}
```

Im trying to select field name from table users but that field doesnt exists so how can I check if the query was executed successfully?
I tried something like

```
if (data.length === 0) {
    res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: 'Wrong password / username'});
}
```

With no success, if I try to res.send(data) it looks like this **[]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `errs` parameter will be an Error object if there was some kind of database or connection-related issue (e.g. bad SQL syntax or some other serious error). For SELECT queries, if `data.length` is zero that means the query was successful but resulted in zero rows.

So your solution of checking `data.length === 0` is correct, but you should also check for and handle the `errs` argument also.

Comment: Doing res.send(data.length); doesnt even output a 0 so the if statement isnt working ;S

Comment: `res.send(data.length);` will treat `data.length` as the HTTP response code since it's a number type. Try `res.send(''+data.length);` instead.